# Nexus tablet 10 inch translucent navigation bar issue Android 5.0.1

Tags: android, navigationbar, translucency

We have used below style to achieve translucent navigation bar and status bar on nexus tablet 10 which has the android 5.0.1 version. It doesn't work on only the Nexus 10inch tablet but same style is working fine on Nexus 5 and 4 (android 5.0.1 version installed in respective device)?? Could you please help us to identify the issue around nexus 10inch tablet?

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
</style>


<style name="APP_THEME" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/SearchViewStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The nexus 10 does not support it unfortunately :/ http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2510252

EDIT: Here is some code from one of my projects that detects if the device can support transparent nav bars.

`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Resources res = getResources();
            int transparencyId = res.getIdentifier("config_enableTranslucentDecor", "bool", "android");
            int[] attrs = new int[]{android.R.attr.windowTranslucentNavigation};
            TypedArray a = mActivity.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
            isTranslucent = a.getBoolean(0, false) && transparencyId > 0 && res.getBoolean(transparencyId);
            a.recycle();
        }`